# How do I get VIM to always open the last opened file?

Tags: vim

I want vim to always open the last opened file instead of an empty un-named file with `VIM - Vi IMproved...` message.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this autocmd into your `.vimrc` which will be triggered when executing `vim` from shell  without arguments:

```c
autocmd VimEnter * if
  \ argc() == 0 &&
  \ bufname("%") == "" |
  \   exe "normal! `0" |
  \ endif
```

Answer (score 2):

[Execute `'0` at the startup of vim.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_the_last_edited_file)